# Open a semi-transparent fragment over another fragment

Tags: android

How can a new fragment `A` be opened on top of another fragment `B` so that the background of `A` is semi-transparent and `B` looks blurry?

I'm using the `NavController` to navigate between the different fragments.
If I just use it to switch between the different fragments then `B` is not shown to me anymore (probably) and I only see `A` even though I have set alpha to be smaller than one.

This is example to fragment `A` -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragments.SelectActionFragment"
    android:background ="#10676767"
    android:alpha="0.2">



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to just put two layouts (FrameLayout would be good) on top of each other, Attach fragment A to the layout with a higher elevation and fragment B to the layout with a lower elevation.

Ex:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentAHolder"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:alpha="0.2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentBHolder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
   .add(R.id.fragmentAHolder, FragmentA())
   .add(R.id.fragmentBHolder, FragmentB())
   .commit()
```